# React conditionally set component property

Tags: reactjs, components

Is there any way I can store inside `header` base on `section.type` different titles like `<p> {section.title1} </p>` or `<p> {section.title2} </p>` ?

```
return (
    <Collapse
        onToggle={onHandleClick}
        header={
            <p> {section.title1} </p>
        }
    </Collapse>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in this way:

```
   header={
            <p> {section.type ? section.title1 : section.title2} </p>
        }
```

Comment: I did it   ..... @paulalexandru

Answer (score 0):

You can a do a conditional render:

```
return (
    <Collapse
        onToggle={onHandleClick}
        header={
           section.type ? <p>{section.title1}</p> : <p>{section.title2}</p>
        }
    </Collapse>
)
```

Comment: This does not work like instagram likes